# Air Conditioning don't blow cold air 2011 Honda civic, dealership shop is quoting my girlfriend $1,600

Tags: honda, ac, civic

My girl friend have a 2010 Honda Civic. It was running smoothly up till now, but the AC Compressor just destroyed itself this past Friday, it don't blow cold air and the compressor sounds make noise. Is this [honda civic a/c common problem](https://www.hexautoparts.com/blog/post/2003-2010-honda-civic-ac-compressor-problems-why-is-the-a-c-not-working-in-my-car.html) for the car?
Either way, the dealership shop is quoting me $1,600 to replace the compressor, clutch, serpentine belt and for an AC recharge.Actually, it's shocked me. Does this sound about right? Or am I getting hosed?
Thanks!

Comment: We don't do prices as there is too much variation between countries and locations...

Comment: Read this carefully. Aftermarket AC compressor comes with a clutch, it's somewhere from 150 to 200 USD. Aftermarket Serpentine belts range from 10 to 30 USD. Recharging freon R134a at best 20 USD.

Comment: Then it is the time : some vehicles need more work than others.... and some places have labour rates cheaper / more expensive and parts vary in price between countries..... Also not all A/C compressors come with clutches some do, some don't...

Comment: Contact me I'll guide you to local work shops, part stores and assist in negotiations. 2011 civic's compressor comes with clutch. Honda loves to charge separately.

Comment: Sounds like a standard dealership price to me. Figure $400-$700 for compressor plus 3-4 hours labor. It's probably time to take it somewhere else.

Comment: $1600 is more than fair if all the components in the system have to be replaced because of crud in the system. I hate changing evaporater cores, as you have to remove the instrument panel, and condenser replacement isn't easy either.

Comment: A whole lot depends on the details of "destroyed itself". Broken shaft under pulley = easy swap. Shattered swashplate and crumbling pistons, you gotta replace everything.   What caused the failure?